# How best to handle and expose Converted Value inside my class

Tags: c#, architecture

In my code behind, I grab a value from the selected index from a radiobuttonlist.

Question is, in some cases I need to use it as a string but other cases I need to convert it to Int32 for use in some methods.

Is it better to:

Convert to int using a property (possible reuse later on)
Convert to int inside just one method that needs it at this moment

I figure a private property will allow reuse across multiple methods internally.  But if only one method really needs it to be an integer and that method uses it in a couple calls by passing it as a string parameter inside that method, just do the conversion there in that method and forget about exposing it as a private property with the assumption that someone may want to use it in some other method in this code behind later.

Answer (score 1):

I would think of this as model view controller. The view sees this value as a String but the actual type of the value in the model is an integer. Therefore you should store it as an integer and then convert it to a String view as needed by the model clients.

Comment: I'm not asking how to store it in the DB using the model.  This is purely how & where to hold the conversion in my code-behind for reuse.  I only have one method right now that needs to use it as an integer (because it's sending it back to the model to insert into the DB for a value we are storing).

Comment: let me explain better.  I am grabbing the selected index value from the radiobuttonlist as so in my code-behind: _someID = rblMyRadiobuttonList.SelectedValue; where _someID is a string because SelectedValue returns the value behind the SelectedText.

Comment: So I need to use the selectedvalue both as a string and integer in various methods in my class.  I thought to expose the conversion to integer as a property for reuse internally now and later on.

Comment: note that _someID is a private string field in my code-behind, that is set inside a click event

Comment: By "model" I didn't necessarily mean the database, I meant your model layer in your code. The principle still applies, store the value in its canonical format as an integer and then let those methods that need it as a String do their own conversion.

Answer (score 0):

**It is better to convert to int [and expose it as] a property**

In general, I would present the value as the most specific type I can put it in.

If the value always has an integer representation, then just present it as an integer property.  If someone needs to use it as a `string`, they can call `.ToString()` themselves to convert it back.

```
private void UpdateValue()
{
   _selectedValue = Int32.Parse(GetSelectedValue());
}

private int _selectedValue;

public int SelectedValue
{
   get { return _selectedValue; }
}
```

In many cases, whoever is using your code won't even need to call `.ToString()`, for example:

```
string description = string.Format("Selected Value: {0}", obj.SelectedValue);
```